# TomCat frozen with flex3 call

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat

Hello i got a problem using Apache-Tomcat v6.0.29.

**The Problem**

My application uses apache tomcat for the java-flex comunication... everithing goes fine most of the time... but sometimes when i call a java function from flex 3 (a function that most of the time works fine)... Tomcat GETS FROZEN.

**Example  (EDIT)**

1- Start tomcat (works)

2- run flex program (works)

3- call the java function downloadLiveViewPicture() (works great)

...
I download lots of live view pictures from a camera and take pictures and re start the live view downloads and everuthing works fine... i call functions form java lile takePicture(), or execute in java sql querys form my database...
...

4- do something else...  (works)

5- call the same java function (sometimes works and sometimes not)
When i go to the main view of my flex app, i i try to re start the downloadLV nothings happen, even if the procedure i use in this point is the same i use and works on point 3...

**Environment**

Backend Java
FrontEnd Flex aplication
Between tjhe: Apache Tomcat v6.0.29

**Solution attempts**

I tried closing tomcat and re opening it after calling again the Java function (Step 5 of example) it works, but this solution is not a viable solution.
At least i want to make it using a java method which closes and re opens the tomcat. I tried using the taskkill comand but it doesnt work...

The other thing that i realized is that if i wait a minute before calling the java function from flex... there is a greater probability that the function will work...

**Thanks!!!**

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more information. What is this Java function doing, are you getting any error output in logs. Can you post the Java function code?

Comment: @KevinD Ok thanks for the comment... the java function is interacting with a camera... I am not getting any output in the log related to this problem. Tomcat gets frozen and nothing happen...

Comment: Matias, I doubt I'll be able to answer you question so I'm just trying to get the information that people with more flex/tomcat experience will need. I doubt they will be able to help you without seeing at least some of the code. At the moment your question can be summarised as "Something doesn't work, sometimes." Try to read your question back to yourself, and try to put yourself in the position of someone who has never seen your code. Now what information would you want to know to try and diagnose this issue?

Comment: Ok thanks for the help... i want to make it easy to read... but i think that i make it extremelly easy... i will edit it...

Comment: Run your app, open jconsole, connect to tomcat, see where it hangs, voilá, you know where the problem is.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Thanks mauricio but i dont know hot to open jconsole... Its an app that i have to download???

Comment: It comes with your JDK instalation, look at the bin directory where your JDK was installed and there is going to be a jsoncole executable in there.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Ok Thanks!!! i found it... but dont get nothing i could use to knw the problem i think...

Comment: Check the threads tab and try to find the thread that is locked, you will see where it is locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly find the problem:

I am using a Camera wich supports only one session simultaneously and TomCat creates new java Threads when i call TomCat from the Flex app. So every thread which wants to interact with the cam get the TomCat frozen if the is another thread interacting with the cam.

Is not a solution buy a good man said: "If you find the problem, you almost find the solution".

So i would have to deal with the one-session problem...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a native API from Java in the server? May be you are initializing the native API every time the method is invoked and that initialization is causing tomcat to fail.

Comment: Yes i am using a native API, but i am not initializing it every time, so i am still trying to deal with this problem. I read something about making sicronized the java methods but i dont know if its improve in some way.

Comment: I also heard that the method Thread.sleep() could make all freeze but i am not sure if its true...